# With PHP, how to get substring "aaa-bbb" from "string1 string2 aaa-bbb string3" when I only know "aaa"?

Tags: php, regex, xpath

Say you have something like a class name:

```
class = "class-1 class-2-something topic-exercise class-3-somemoretext"
```

Sometimes there will be a string in this class along the lines `topic-bbb`. I get such elements via `xpath` in PHP:

```
$contenttypes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'topic')]");
```

But then I need to get the rest of the string. So if I have `topic-exercise`, I need to get `exercise`. I can get `exercise` easily from `topic-exercise`, so really this comes down to extracting `topic-exercise`.

How can I do this with an Xpath query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're able to get the whole string so you only need help extracting what you need from it, in that case this should help:

```
<?php 

$string = "class-1 class-2-something topic-exercise class-3-somemoretext topic-more";

preg_match_all('/topic-(\S*)\s?/', $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[1]);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => exercise
    [1] => more
)
```

**//EDIT**

A way to solve this without regex would be to split the string into each class, then check if class if it has an hyphen and split the string by it, if the left part is the keyword you're looking for (topic), then the right part is the one you want, like this:

```
<?php 

$string = "class-1 class-2-something topic-exercise class-3-somemoretext something topic-more";

function get_topics($str, $prefix = 'topic') {
    $matches = [];
    $classes = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($classes as $class) {
        if(strpos($class, '-') !== false) {
            list($pre, $post) = explode('-', $class);
            if($pre == $prefix && !empty($post)) {
                array_push($matches, $post);
            }
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( get_topics($string) );
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: THanks! I was about to do all sorts of strpos and searching after the hyphen, but this is perfect!

Comment: Yeah, if you don’t know regex, this could involve a not-too-complex array_map passing elements to an anonymous function

Comment: Hi, just for entertaiment purposes, I added a way to solve it without regex since I saw your and Stephen comments. Greetings.